# Javascript arguments as array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments

so I have a button with this event:

```
onmousedown="hideElements('\x22cartview\x22,\x22other\x22')"
```

and then this function hideElements:

```
function hideElements(what)
  {
  var whichElements=[what];
  alert(whichElements[0]);
  }
```

I want it to alert "cartview" but it alerts

> "cartview","other"

I am aware of the arguments object but in this case I don't know how to use it to access the individual strings that are comma separated.  Probably there is an easy solution but I am kind of new to this.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with your context, but you should probably take a look at jQuery. If you are new to web development and don't know about it, you'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
onmousedown="hideElements([ 'cartview', 'other' ])"
```

and then:

```
function hideElements(what) {
    alert(what[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the real problem is that you're passing an string, not an array. So you'd do something like:

```
function hideElements(/* String */ what) {
    alert(what.split(',')[0]);
}
```

or with an array:

```
function hideElements(/* Array<String> */ what) {
    alert(what[0]);
}
```

or passing multiple strings directly into the function:

```
function hideElements(/* String */ what) {
    alert(arguments[0]);
}
```